# React-Native : is there a way to control the ripple duration in TouchableNativeFeedback?

Tags: react-native

I used TouchableNativeFeedback for a View in my code .Onpressing that View i m navigating to the other page.But On press the ripple effect takes a second or more sometimes to complete and navigate to the next page.I am calling a function on press of the View as shown below.

```
<TouchableNativeFeedback    
    underlayColor='#A3A7AC' 
    onPress={this.props.mainNavAction.bind(null,categoryitems[index])}
    background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('#A3A7AC',false)}>     
    <View >
        ............
    </View>       
</TouchableNativeFeedback>
```